# Cramer-Rao lower bound always possible?

Tags: probability, statistics, parameter-estimation

I am trying do find:

$$\frac{1}{E\left[\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\alpha}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (m-X_i)}{1-\alpha}\right)^2\right]}$$

But I can't seem to do it. Perhaps it isn't always possible.

$\def\a{\alpha}$
$X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n$ are randomly sampled from the binomial distribution with the pf:

$$P_X(x) = Pr(X=x) = \binom m x \a^{x} (1-\a)^{m-x},\quad x=0,1,2,\dots,m$$

$m$ is a given constant and $\alpha\in(0,1)$ is an unknown parameter.

The MLE is:
$$\hat \alpha=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i}m$$
and I have
$E(\hat{\a}) = \a$, $\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\a})=\dfrac{\a(1-\a)}{mn}$

---

I think it best to try to work out $\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\alpha}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (m-X_i)}{1-\alpha}\right)^2$ first, but I am not sure how to expand such a thing, if it were $E(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)$ and easy terms like that, I would see that it is equal to $n\a$, but here I have to square it first.

Comment: You are withholding a lot of information.  One cannot find an expected value without knowing anything about the probability distributions of the random variables involved.  When one speaks of a log-likelihood, one has in mind a family of probability distributions, often indexed by one or more real parameters.  You're withholding all of that.  How can you expect anyone to know what you're talking about if you don't tell us things like that?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry I didn't mean to post and I am currently editing

Comment: OK, I'll await further edits.

Comment: @MichaelHardy For the Fisher information, am I better going going the second derivative direction? It would probably bypass my issue?

Comment: I'll be back later $\ldots\ldots\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

Start with rewriting the expression occurring in the exprectation:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
  Y &=& \frac{1}{\alpha} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k - \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(m-X_k\right) \\ &=& \frac{1}{\alpha} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k - \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \left(n \cdot m- \sum_{k=1}^n X_k\right) \\ &=& -\frac{n \cdot m}{1-\alpha} + \frac{1}{\alpha\left(1-\alpha\right)} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k  \end{eqnarray}
$$
Since $X_k$ are all iid, the random variable $Z=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ is known to also be Binomial distributed, specifically $Z \sim \mathrm{Binom}\left(n \cdot m, p\right)$. This is easy to understand, since each binomial random variable can be though of sum of $m$ independent Bernoulli trial outcomes.

Notice that $$
 \mathbb{E}\left(Z\right) = n \cdot m \cdot \alpha 
$$
which implies that $\mathbb{E}\left(Y\right)=0$.

Now:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
 \mathbb{E}\left(Y^2\right) &=&  \mathbb{E}\left(\left(-\frac{n \cdot m}{1-\alpha} + \frac{1}{\alpha\left(1-\alpha\right)} Z \right)^2 \right) = \frac{\mathbb{E}\left(\left(Z- n\cdot m \cdot \alpha\right)^2 \right)}{\alpha^2 (1-\alpha)^2}  = \frac{\mathbb{Var}\left(Z\right)}{\alpha^2 (1-\alpha)^2} \\& =& \frac{n \cdot m \cdot \alpha \cdot (1-\alpha)}{\alpha^2 (1-\alpha)^2} = \frac{n \cdot m}{\alpha \cdot (1-\alpha)}
\end{eqnarray}
$$